# How to save application preferences in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, preferences

Is there a native way to save preferences in Mac OS ?

Can I write preferences into application package content directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NSUserDefaults class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the standard way to save application preferences.

There are a number of tutorials / examples online (Google is your friend):

[NSUserDefaults Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

Answer (score 1):

The native way is to use [NUSuserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059-BCIDJFHD). You won't want to write into the application directory for a number of reasons, not least because different users can have different preferences.